# Chart.js does not group equal labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a time chart using Chart.js. Apparently it's working, however I'm having difficulties with the labels that are not grouped when equal, I believed that Chart.js did this on its own but I see that it is not. Note that, in the image, there are two "Task 2".

[image: chart]

```js
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Task 2', 'Task 1', 'Task 3'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Task 2',
        data: [[0, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
      },
      {
        label: 'Task 1',
        data: [[0, 0], [2, 5], [0, 0]]
      },
      {
        label: 'Task 3',
        data: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 7]]
      },
      {
        label: 'Task 2',
        data: [[7, 9], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      x: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

My question is if I mapped the data wrong or if it is a chartjs limitation.

Comment: No, `chart.js` doesn't group datasets by identical labels. You have four datasets; `label` is just a property. Were it intended as an index, it would probably have defined `datasets` as an object, with `labels` as properties, the way `options.scales` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use Apexchart which provides a simpler solution to my problem:

https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/advanced/